# (Graphs API/FQL) Retrieving/processing group join requests

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-group

Assuming I have a user token with the necessary permissions, how might I go about retrieving a list of the users who have submitted requests to join a particular group? For example, using the FQL Query:

```
SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid=XXXX
```

I can easily retrieve a list of the ids for the users who are currently part of group XXXX. Unfortunately, this list doesn't include the ids for the users who have *requested* to join the group. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for that functionality; requests to join a group can neither be seen nor acted upon in the API

Comment: That's quite unfortunate, I was hoping to automate verifying those names against a separate database... time to rethink things.

Anyway, thanks for the info.